# C++ Function return string?

Tags: c++

so I'm kinda new to c++ (actually very new) and I was messing around with my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string aString()
{
    cout << "Car" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Word:" << aString() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to get something like: "Word: Car".

It ended up not working and showing a bunch of weird characters. My question is can a function return a string like an integer does?

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: `using namespace std;` is not a good idea - please google it

Comment: It certainly can. Except that you're not returning a string. Your compiler should've issued a warning, which you probably ignored. Do not ignore warning messages from your compiler. The compiler does not issue warning messages just because it feels like it.

Comment: You forgot to `#include <string>`  The code is not guaranteed to compile.

Answer (score 10):

> My question is can a function return a string like an integer does?

Sure, you want to write

```
string aString()
{
    return "Car";
 // ^^^^^^
}
```

---

If the function declares a return type, you actually need to return something, otherwise you have undefined behavior.

The compiler should have issued a warning about that.

`std::cout` is used to print out values at the terminal, not to return them from functions.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I'm trying to learn c++, do you know any good sites? I have almost no experience with programming languages (only a bit c#, html, js)

Comment: @MikeWu Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).